# How do you utilize ComponentSearch for Spring Beans when all the files are in their respective packages?

Tags: java, spring

[image]

I'm pretty new utilizing Spring Beans and Hibernate.
I keep getting a "Parameter 0 of method demo in service.ProjectApplication required a bean of type 'Repositories.TransactionRepository' that could not be found." error. I know it's because the file that i run springApplication is not in the same directory as the repository I've made; however, I tried using ComponentScan with no luck (I actually think i might be scanning the wrong directory). Any tips on how to correctly scan the "Repositories directory" from the service directory? I mean It does work if I put them in the same repository but it does look cleaner this way.

Also, any advice on how to manage my directories/packages/files?

Comment: Can you show your code implementation and error? Without code it would be difficult to solve your queries?

Comment: Can you try @EnableJpaRepositories({“packagename”}).

Comment: @GauravRai1512 Sorry, I'm not really used to posting here but thanks a lot man that actually worked!!

Comment: I have added this point in answer section.can you accept the answer? as your query has been resolved. so that solution will help in future to some other user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below annotation

```
@EnableJpaRepositories({“packagename”}).
```

might help you to resolve your issue.